# PHP not working correctly?

Tags: php, email, hotmail

I have this PHP code here, which should sent the Names, Email and comment of the user to an email. Although it doesn't seem to be working any more. I've been using this code as a basis for my contact form for many years. Now they're just not working.

```
Your message is being sent...
<?php


$emailSubject = 'A message from: '.$_POST['name'] .' '.'-'.' ' .'Email Adress: ' .$_POST['email'];
$webMaster = 'webmaster@gmail.com';


$name1 = $_POST['name1'];
$name2 = $_POST['name2'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sub = $_POST['sub'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
<b>First Name: $name1 </b><br> 
<b>Last Name: $name2 </b><br>
Email: $email <br>
Subject: $sub <br>
Comments: $comments <br>
EOD;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
$headers);

$theResults = <<<EOD
<html>
<head>
<title>Your message is being sent...</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4;URL=http://www.google.co.uk">
<style type="text/css">
<!--

body {
background-color: #25EA5F;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
line-height: normal;
font-weight: normal;
color: #30489E;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 350px;
margin-left: 550px;
width: 800px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

</html>
</body>
EOD;
echo "$theResults";
?>
```

It's very confusing and annoying. Messages when sent to Hotmail don't even appear, so that'll force the clients to get a new email because of it, and when sent to Google... Does it not accept **$_POST** or something?

[image: This is what happens when I send a message to Google.]

As you can see, the SCRIPT does work, it's just with G-mail none of the important information seems to show up, and on Hotmail the messages don't even send/appear!! Thanks for your help. Here is the HTML if needed.

```
<div class="contactwrap">
<div class="ContactInner">
<div class="ContactTitle">CONTACT US</div>

<form action="Scripts/contact.php" method="post">
  <div class="containboxes">

<span id="sprytextfield1">
<label for="text1"></label>
<input name="text1" type="text" class="inputstyle" id="name1" value="First Name"     size="5" maxlength="5" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span>

<span id="sprytextfield2">
<label for="text2"></label>
<input name="text2" type="text" class="inputright" id="name2" value="Last Name" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span>

<span id="sprytextfield3">
<label for="text3"></label>
<input name="text3" type="text" class="inputstyleBelow" id="email" value="E-mail Address" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span><span     class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>

<span id="sprytextfield4">
<label for="text4"></label>
<input name="text4" type="text" class="inputrightBelow" id="sub" value="Message Subject" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span>

<span id="sprytextarea1">
<label for="textarea1"></label>
<textarea name="textarea1" cols="45" rows="5" class="inputstyleMsg" id="comments">Message Here</textarea>
<span id="countsprytextarea1">&nbsp;</span><span class="textareaRequiredMsg"></span>    <span class="textareaMinCharsMsg">Minimum number of characters not met.</span><span     class="textareaMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span>


<div class="sendbtn"><input name="Submit message" type="submit" class="submitmail" value="" /></div>
</div>
</form>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to var_dump your $_POST values to check if they are really received by your script ? Also, about Hotmail, you should check the spam folder. Empty messages like this have high chance to finish here.

Comment: `<input name="text1" type="text" class="inputstyle" id="name1" name = 'name1' value="First Name"     size="5" maxlength="5" />` you need to mention name in for the input type

Comment: Clement, I've not tried it as I wouldn't know to go about doing it. As I said, I've used this method a long time. And I've checked Hotmail time and time again. I think Outlook may have messed with something, they appear to not even be received by it, not even in the Spam/Junk folder. Which is strange, because it used to work perfectly fine!

Comment: Oh no. I just figured it out, I think. Hold on a moment.

Comment: Ugh!!! I'm SO stupid!

Comment: I completely forgot about the ID's! Let me fix them up real quick. Hold on.

Comment: Sidenote: There's no opening `<body>` tag in your code, while echoing `echo "$theResults";` outside `</html></body>` tags. Plus, injecting POST variables outside. This will not render as being valid HTML.

Comment: I've just fixed that now. Thanks. Any reason why you don't think it'll be working with Hotmail/Outlook? Not in the spam folders or anything.

Comment: You'd need to follow this convention: `<?php // executable code with nothing that needs echoing ?><!DOCTYPE html><head>CSS stuff etc.</head><body><?php // echo text and stuff and show code from execute if required ?>Standard HTML codes</body></html><?php // executable code with nothing that needs echoing ?>` that would be considered as valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form fields are incorrect. `id` is **NOT** used in form submission. the `name` parameter is. Since you've named your form fields as `text1`, `text2`, etc... but are looking for `name1` and similar in your PHP code, you're trying to retrieve non-existent fields.

e.g. you have:

```
<input name="text1" type="text" class="inputstyle" id="name1" value="First Name"     size="5" maxlength="5" />
$_POST['name1'];
```

no, that field will actually be `$_POST['text1']`.

Comment: It was a simple mistake. Is there a way to sent emails to two places at once? I'm testing it now. Silly, silly mistake. I've been working all day and not eaten :( Hmm..

Comment: just call mail() twice with two different addresses, or use a custom header with a `cc:`

Comment: Okay. It seems to be working now, still investigating why it won't work with Hotmail though.

Comment: Any reason why you don't think it'll be working with Hotmail/Outlook? Not in the spam folders or anything.

Comment: email's complicated. just because your code is working doesn't mean the rest of the postal system is. e.g. php's job is the equivalent of taking your envelope and walking it down the street to the mailbox. If the mail carriers go on strike, or the mail truck explodes, that's not php's fault and there'd be no way for PHP to know it had happened. it did its job - the letter was dropped in the box.